# Autocomplete email functionality in UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, autocomplete, uitextfield

[image: My Image]

I want to implement a **same autocomplete email functionality** as showing in above screen in my **UITextField**

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows,
1)store the emails 
2)When the user starts type the text in textField search the stored valu and display the values in UITableView

You should use the following delegate of UITextField

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Answer (score 0):

What kingOfBliss said is the correct way. anyhow i will provide you some logic of the code.
Try tis code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

for(NSString *particularEmail in arrayContainsAllEmailAddress)
    {
            NSString *firstLetter = @"";
            NSInteger stringlen=[string length];
            if(particularEmail.length >= stringlen)
            {
                firstLetter = [particularEmail substringToIndex:stringlen];
            }
            if(firstLetter.length > 0)
            {
                if([string.uppercaseString isEqualToString:firstLetter.uppercaseString])
                    {
                        [tableArray addObject:particularEmail];
                        //tableArray is the array which u will load into the tableview. This contains the emails that matches your search name.
                    }       
            }
    }
    // Add your tableArray into UITableView
}
```

Comment: Or use `NSPredicate` and `NSArray`'s `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` to get the array you need to display in just a couple lines of code.